# Lightning layoutItem not rendering

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, page-layout

Hi I'm creating a custom lightning page template. i need a header, left sidebar, 3 middle components, a right sidebar. the problem is that two of my layoutItems are not rendering properly, just NaN is displayed? code is below

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
<lightning:layoutItem size="3" flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-round-xx_small">{!v.left}</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="2" flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-round-xxx_small">{!v.center}</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="2" flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-round-xxx_small">{!v.center-top-mid}</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="2" flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-round-xxx_small">{!v.center-top-right}</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="3" flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-round-xx_small">{!v.right}</lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

[image: Page layout in app builder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` is the mathematical operator "subtraction". As far as I can tell, you're not supposed to use any sort of name that you could not use in JavaScript, which means you should stick to letters and numbers.

Consider using camelCase instead:

```
{!v.centerTopMid}
```

Basically, your original expression is trying to calculate "v.center minus top minus mid", for example. Since `top` and `mid` are not valid attributes, it ends up in a NaN (Not a Number) state.